# Scrapy Splash returns empty list

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

I am trying to scrape images and some product information of clothes with Scrapy and Splash.
I would like to get the image with just the product (so no model). 
[Such as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m47VJ.jpg) from https://www2.hm.com/nl_nl/productpage.0220094001.html

However, if I try to get the src in the Scrapy shell with

response.xpath('//figure[contains(@class, "secondary")]//img//@src').extract()

an empty list is returned.

Does anybody know how I could get the src of these secondary images?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check the json that is in `response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "productArticleDetails =")]/text()')`. It contains all the data about product on page, with images.

Comment: How could I extract the desired link from the json? Because there are no classes or ids in the text that is returned.

Comment: `json.loads(response.text)`. For more information, see the documentation of Python’s [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: If this approach is used, Splash should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Splash to render the page (as you mentioned), your xpath should be working correctly.
You can test it in scrapy shell like this:

```
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www2.hm.com/nl_nl/productpage.0220094001.html&timeout=100&wait=0.5'
```

Your xpath gives a list of 5 images:

```
response.xpath('//figure[contains(@class, "secondary")]//img//@src').extract()
['//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/04/2f/042fded3bfa88dda5680a6470f12f180bca4739e.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_dresses_maxidresses],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],res[s],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]', 
'//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/8b/03/8b03a5491cc1fdfd27c7a308ad8fab2e1d408754.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_dresses_maxidresses],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],res[s],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]', 
'//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/11/28/1128425ddada72796f5f4ad3b46d5836957f9522.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_dresses_maxidresses],type[LOOKBOOK],res[m],res[s],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]', 
'//lp2.hm.com/hmgoepprod?set=source[/79/63/796367ae5cfea46bf6b8eb2e1afe2fb5e54e86f4.jpg],origin[dam],category[ladies_dresses_maxidresses],type[DESCRIPTIVESTILLLIFE],res[s],hmver[1]&call=url[file:/product/main]', 
'//lp2.hm.com/hmprod?set=source[/model/2017/E00 0220094 001 08 3075.jpg],width[843],height[985],x[353],y[123],type[DETAIL],res[s]&hmver=0&call=url[file:/product/main]']
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me. I get an empty list: In [14]: fetch('http://192.168.99.101:8050/render.html?url=https://www2.hm.com/nl_nl/productpage.0220094001.html&timeou
    ...: t=100&wait=0.5')
2019-02-06 19:43:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <GET http://192.168.99.101:8050/render.html?url=https://www2.hm.com/nl_nl/productpage.0220094001.html&timeout=100&wait=0.5> (referer: None)

In [15]: response.xpath('//figure[contains(@class, "secondary")]//img//@src').extract()
Out[15]: []

Comment: If you run scrapy splash with the standard settings, you can only use a maximum time-out of 90 I think. Can you try like this? `scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www2.hm.com/nl_nl/productpage.0220094001.html&timeout=90&wait=0.5'`